# Retrofit with kotlin throws Failed to connect to {ServerName/IpAddress}

Tags: android, api, kotlin, server, retrofit

I am facing strange issue while using retrofit2 and kotlin. I am new to Kotlin.
When I hit an API more than 6 times, I am getting this  **Failed to connect to {ServerName/IpAddress}** error.

Here is the code for interface

```
 companion object {
    lateinit var context: Context
    private fun getHttpClient(): OkHttpClient.Builder {
       return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
                    level = if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
                })
    }
    fun retrofitBuilder(): Retrofit.Builder {
        val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConstants.BASE_URL)
                //.addConverterFactory(ToStringConverterFactory())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    }

    fun create(): ApiInterface {
        val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
        val retrofit = retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(AppConstants.BASE_URL)
                .client(getHttpClient().build())
                .build()

        return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    }

    fun createWithAuth(context: Context, token: String?): ApiInterface {
        this.context = context
        val httpClient = getHttpClient()

        httpClient.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val req = chain.request()
            val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
                    .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "None")
                    .method(req.method, req.body)
                    .build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }

        val retrofits = retrofitBuilder().client(httpClient.build()).build()
        return retrofits.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    }
}
```

I checked whether the server has issue, But I checked in Postman by using Runner to hit same API 100 times in loop. Postman returns success response each time.

please Help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In question above, the code in **Companion Object {}** is written in Interface class where my endPoints are present.

And created this class similar to the above code but as a separate class.

```
class ApiClient private constructor() {
companion object {
    private val retrofit: Retrofit? = null
    private var context: Context? = null


    private val httpClient: OkHttpClient.Builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            //.addInterceptor(LoggingInterceptor())


    private val builder: Retrofit.Builder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

    fun  createService(ctx: Context): ApiInterface {
        context = ctx
        val retrofit: Retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build()
        return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    }


    fun createServiceWithAuth(ctx: Context, authToken: String?): ApiInterface {
        context = ctx
        if (authToken != null) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
                @Throws(IOException::class)
                override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                    val original: Request = chain.request()
                    val request: Request = original.newBuilder() //.header("User-Agent", "Your-App-Name")
                            .header("Authorization", "bearer $authToken")
                            .header("Accept-Encoding", "None")
                            .method(original.method, original.body)
                            .build()return chain.proceed(request)
                }
            })
        }
        val retrofit: Retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build()
        return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    }
  }
}
```

I still don't get what the issue in these two codes {Question asked, and this answer}. But this answer is not giving such issue to me.

If anybody can explain me it will be helpful to me as well as others.

Thanks